# Too few parameters. Expected 2 In Talend

Tags: sql, ms-access, talend

I am firing a Update query in ms-access 2013.But this update query will execute for different row on different condition.I know that in Access we cannot use "CASE...WHEN" condition.In access we need to go for **Switch()** function.Below is my Update Query:

```
UPDATE T_Generated_OpportunityLine SET IsUploadable = Switch(
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTLRC -Swiss CCO Standards' AND Amount_c>=5000,"Y",
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTLRC -Swiss CCO Standards' AND Amount_c<5000,"N",
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTWDA -Swiss WDE Standards' AND Amount_c>=5000,"Y",
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTWDA -Swiss WDE Standards' AND Amount_c<5000,"N",
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTFDS - FD ENCLOSURE SYSTEMS' AND Amount_c>=30000,"Y",
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTFDS - FD ENCLOSURE SYSTEMS' AND Amount_c<30000,"N",
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTCMS - CABLE MNGT SYSTEMS' AND Amount_c>=25000,"Y",
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTCMS - CABLE MNGT SYSTEMS' AND Amount_c<25000,"N",
Lowestlevelvalue_c='DOOR ENTRY SYSTEM' AND Amount_c>=15000,"Y",
Lowestlevelvalue_c='DOOR ENTRY SYSTEM' AND Amount_c<15000,"N");
```

This query is running properly from access 2013.But when I am using this query in **Talend5.4** in the "**tAccessRow**" element then I am getting the following piece of error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2
```

**Before Update my Table row looks like this:**

```
    LowestLevelInPyramid_c  Lowestlevelvalue_c          LineStatus_c    Quantity_c  Amount_c    LineClosedate_c  IsUploadable
    ProductLine             PTLRC -Swiss CCO Standards  Pending         1           9600        11/21/2013
```

**After Update It will be**

```
    LowestLevelInPyramid_c  Lowestlevelvalue_c          LineStatus_c    Quantity_c  Amount_c    LineClosedate_c  IsUploadable
    ProductLine             PTLRC -Swiss CCO Standards  Pending         1           9600        11/21/2013       Y/N
```

this **"Y/N"** will be evaluated based on the condition as explained in above mentioned query.Here each row stands for opportunityLine.Through update I am determining whether a particular row is uploadable to Client CRM System or Not.If its 'Y' then it will be uploadable if its "N" then it will not be uploadable.

Can anyone provide any suitable solution to this??

Comment: Don't do this in a tAccessRow. Put the logic in a tMap instead.

Comment: well as far as I know tMap is generally used for mapping purpose.and I am trying to update a particular column of a table through this query.so how can I implement this using tMap?

Comment: Your update statement looks unclear to me. Can you provide an example of your data before the update and what it should look like afterwards?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I have edited my question with an example.I hope it helps.I think Talend is not identifying the Access Switch() function

Answer (score 1):

Typically this sort of transformation is normally done in a tMap or a tJavaRow component rather than trying to nest a bunch of logic inside a DML statement. This should make it much more amenable to future changes and performance tends to be very good with a simple transformation like this as Talend has no need to buffer the entire data set and can read from the source, transform and update the target in a flow.

When dealing with very large data sets (typically 1 million row+) you might prefer to keep the data inside the database and perform the transformation there using a database row component or, better yet, the ELT components that Talend offers.

A very simple ETL job setup might look something like:

[image: Sample job layout]

This job connects to a MySQL Database and then pulls all of the data from the table into a schema.

The main part of the job happens in the tMap that has a configuration like this:

[image: tMap variable configuration]

In the above screenshot, I've created a variable that calculates whether something is uploadable and is so it is `true`. This is repeated for every type of `LowestLevelValue_c`.

And then finally we use a ternary operator in the value for `IsUploadable`:

[image: IsUploadable ternary operator]

If any of the variables are `true` then `IsUpload` is set as "Y", otherwise it's set to "N".

The remainder of my job then uses a tLogRow to print the results to the console but you could use a tAccessOutput component set to update your Access database. Make sure to have configured your schema to have a unique key to update on (in this case you could probably use `LowestLevelValue_c` and `Amount_c` if you are lacking a unique primary key for the table).

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly guessed, the problem is with the `Switch()` function.  This is a VBA function, not a native Jet/ACE SQL function.  That's why it works from Access and fails from Talend.

To make this work you need to translate your `Switch()` statement to a nested `IIf()`.  `IIf()` is a native Jet/ACE statement.  It will be a bit uglier than the `Switch()` function but should actually perform better because it uses short-circuit boolean logic.

Comment: I'd still be concerned about putting the logic in a nested IIF() rather than using Talend to hold the logic for this. If you were talking about millions of records in a traditional RDBMS the performance caveats would hold but this is Access and likely to be in the order of thousands/tens of thousands of rows at most.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.The problem was with **"Y/N"**.In Talend we need to use **'Y' or 'N'**.My Modified query structure look like this:

```
UPDATE T_Generated_OpportunityLine SET IsUploadable = Switch(
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTLRC -Swiss CCO Standards' AND Amount_c>=5000,'Y',
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTLRC -Swiss CCO Standards' AND Amount_c<5000,'N',
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTWDA -Swiss WDE Standards' AND Amount_c>=5000,'Y',
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTWDA -Swiss WDE Standards' AND Amount_c<5000,'N',
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTFDS - FD ENCLOSURE SYSTEMS' AND Amount_c>=30000,'Y',
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTFDS - FD ENCLOSURE SYSTEMS' AND Amount_c<30000,'N',
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTCMS - CABLE MNGT SYSTEMS' AND Amount_c>=25000,'Y',
Lowestlevelvalue_c='PTCMS - CABLE MNGT SYSTEMS' AND Amount_c<25000,'N',
Lowestlevelvalue_c='DOOR ENTRY SYSTEM' AND Amount_c>=15000,'Y',
Lowestlevelvalue_c='DOOR ENTRY SYSTEM' AND Amount_c<15000,'N');
```